# How can I force a file download on IIS 6.0 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis-6

I am using IIS 6.0. I have a file with no extension that is saved on my server, If I try to download this file it gives me a 404 page, how can I force the server to send the file as downloadable if the file exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get IIS to download the file it needs to have a file extension because IIS will only server file types that have been registered in the MIME Types collection. And in order for a file type to be registered under a MIME type it will need an extension.

You could build a simple ASP.NET HttpHandler that issues the file. That will work.

Comment: Any clues about how to build the HttpHandler ?